# Retrieve Variable From Parent Script Inside Prefab Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This project is within Unity, is 2D, and is a basic multiplayer snake game. I am currently trying to fix an issue where the orientation of the snakes body segments is facing the correct direction.

I have two scripts, Snake.cs and SnakeBodySprites.cs

Inside the game object "SnakeHead" which contains the script Snake.cs and has a prefab called "SnakeBody" which holds a script "SnakeBodySprites". My goal is to retrieve the list of segment transformations declared within the Snake.cs script, so that I can use it in my SnakeBodySprites script to compare if the transformations before and after are at certain X and Y coordinates. Giving that prefab a certain sprite depending on the result.

**snakebodysprites.cs script:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SnakeBodySprites : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Snake SnakeScript;

    //sprites for snake body
    public Sprite SnakeBodyHorizontal;
    public Sprite SnakeBodyVertical;
    public Sprite SnakeBodyCornerLeftDown;
    public Sprite SnakeBodyCornerRightDown;
    public Sprite SnakeBodyCornerLeftUp;
    public Sprite SnakeBodyCornerRightUp;

    private int orientation = 7;

    //Snake myScript = SnakeBodySprites.GetComponentInParent<Snake>();
    //myScript.myVariable = whatever // set variable
    //myScript.myFucntion() // runs function 

    //GameObject.GetComponentInParent


    //If there is an object to the left and to the right, if yes, you're a horizontal piece
    //If there is a piece above and below you, you are a vertical piece
    //If there is a piece above and to the left, you're a corner piece
    //if there is a piece above and to the right, you're a corner piece
    //if there is a piece below and to the right, you're a corner piece
    //if there is a piece below and to the left, you're a corner piece

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //Debug.Log();

        if (orientation == 1){
            Debug.Log("horizontal");
        } else if (orientation == 2){
            Debug.Log("vertical");
        }
        else if (orientation == 3){
            Debug.Log("CornerLeftDown");
        }
        else if (orientation == 4){
            Debug.Log("CornerRightDown");
        }
        else if (orientation == 5){
            Debug.Log("CornerLeftUp");
        }
        else if (orientation == 6){
            Debug.Log("CornerRightUp");
        }
    }
}
```

**snake.cs script:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Snake : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Vector2 _direction = Vector2.right;
    private KeyCode lastHitKey = KeyCode.D;

    public Transform segmentPrefab;
    public int initialSize = 3;
    public Sprite SnakeHeadUp;
    public Sprite SnakeHeadRight;
    public Sprite SnakeHeadLeft;
    public Sprite SnakeHeadDown;
    public List<Transform> _segments = new List<Transform>();

    private void Start()
    {
        ResetState();
    }


    // Update: Updated Once Per Time (Edit -> Project Settings -> Time (0.09) to change difficulty!)
    // This function is controlling the direction our snake moves.
    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && lastHitKey != KeyCode.S) {
            this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = SnakeHeadUp;
            lastHitKey = KeyCode.W;
            _direction = Vector2.up;
        } 
        
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S) && lastHitKey != KeyCode.W){
            this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = SnakeHeadDown;
            lastHitKey = KeyCode.S;
            _direction = Vector2.down;
        } 
        
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) && lastHitKey != KeyCode.D) {
            this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = SnakeHeadLeft;
            lastHitKey = KeyCode.A;
            _direction = Vector2.left;
        } 
        
        else if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D) && lastHitKey != KeyCode.A)
        {
            this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = SnakeHeadRight;
            lastHitKey = KeyCode.D;
            _direction = Vector2.right;
        }
    }

    //This transforms the position of our snake head, rounded to a whole number. This should force our snake to move in a grid.
    public void FixedUpdate()
    {

        for (int i = _segments.Count - 1; i > 0; i--){
            _segments[i].position = _segments[i - 1].position;
        }


        this.transform.position = new Vector3(
            Mathf.Round(this.transform.position.x) + _direction.x,
            Mathf.Round(this.transform.position.y) + _direction.y,
            0.0f
        );

    }

    //Function handles the logic of iterating in reverse from a list of prefabs of our snake segments, to create a new snake segment.
    private void Grow()
    {
        Transform segment = Instantiate(this.segmentPrefab);
        segment.position = _segments[_segments.Count - 1].position; //each segment inherits position

        _segments.Add(segment);
    }

    //Function handles the logic of resetting the state of our game upon collision with objects other than food
    private void ResetState(){

        //emptying the snakelist
        for(int i = 1; i < _segments.Count; i++)
        {
            Destroy(_segments[i].gameObject);
        }

        _segments.Clear();
        _segments.Add(this.transform);

        //resetting our snake from 1 back to initialsize (3)
        for(int i = 1; i < this.initialSize; i++)
        {
            _segments.Add(Instantiate(this.segmentPrefab));
            //initalizing the original segments
            _segments[i].position = new Vector3(
            -50.0f,
            0.0f,
            0.0f
        );
        }

        this.transform.position = new Vector3(
            -5.0f,
            0.0f,
            0.0f
        );
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
            if (other.tag == "Food") {
                Grow();
            } else if (other.tag == "Obstacle") {
                ResetState();
        }
    }
}
```

I was working on this solution for awhile, and you can see a lot of debugging / testing comments in the snakebodysprites.cs script. Private int orientation is just me testing orientation, I intended to change this to a different value, and have the if commands set the prefab component to a sprite when I was able to retrieve the necessery information.

P.S. If you have any small tips on better coding practice, also feel free to mention it, trying to improve my programming skills :)

Comment: If I understand your explanation correctly, when you instantiate a new segment (in `Grow`), can you get the SnakeBodySprites script on that segment (using `segment.GetComponent<SnakeBodySprites>` and then pass the Snake script instance into the SnakeBodySprites instance via a function or field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your title see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76069187/7111561).

However, answering your actual issue(s), I would rather set this from top down / meanin the `Snake` script knows and controls  the `SnakeBodySprites`, not the other way round poll checking for any state changes. I would then also properly call it `SnakeSegment` instead.

First of all for this I would make your prefab already of the correct type

```
public SnakeSegment segmentPrefab;
// I know originally you als stored the snake itself here
// we will skip that and rather update the first segment after the head explicitly - see bottom
public List<SnakeSegment> _segments = new ();
```

then add a public property to actually change the direction value, I would use an enum instead of plain `int`:

```
public enum SnakeSegmentType
{
    horizontal,
    vertical,
    CornerLeftDown,
    CornerRightDown,
    CornerLeftUp,
    CornerRightUp
}

public class SnakeSegment : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Just assuming that's what you are using
    [SerializeField] private SpriteRenderer SpriteRenderer;

    [SerializeField] private Sprite SnakeBodyHorizontal;
    [SerializeField] private Sprite SnakeBodyVertical;
    [SerializeField] private Sprite SnakeBodyCornerLeftDown;
    [SerializeField] private Sprite SnakeBodyCornerRightDown;
    [SerializeField] private Sprite SnakeBodyCornerLeftUp;
    [SerializeField] private Sprite SnakeBodyCornerRightUp;

    private SnakeSegmentType type;

    // Need to have a public getter anyway to properly inherit the value
    public SnakeSegmentType Type
    {
        get => type;
        set =>
        {
            type = value;

            // in the setter also update the visuals accordingly
            SpriteRenderer.sprite = value switch
            {
                vertical => SnakeBodyVertical,
                CornerLeftDown => SnakeBodyCornerLeftDown,
                CornerRightDown => SnakeBodyCornerRightDown,
                CornerLeftUp => SnakeBodyCornerLeftUp,
                CornerRightUp => SnakeBodyCornerRightUp,
                _ => SnakeBodyHorizontal
            };
        }
    }
}
```

A `SnakeSegment` doesn't need any further knowledge, not even where the values comes from. The `Snake` will rather handle that and pass it on.

Then in `Snake` adobt to the changed types first

```
private void ResetState()
{
    //emptying the snakelist
    // foreach is fine now since the head (this) is not in here anymore
    foreach(var segment in _segments)
    {
        Destroy(segment.gameObject);
    }

    _segments.Clear();

    // initializing with initialSize including the head
    for(int i = 1; i < initialSize; i++)
    {
        var segment = Instantiate(segmentPrefab);
        _segment.transform.position = 50 * i * Vector3.left;
        _segments.Add(segment);
    }

    transform.position = 5 * Vector3.left;
}
```

and then always inherit both the position and type

```
private void Grow()
{
    var segment = Instantiate(segmentPrefab);

    // inherit last position and orientation
    segment.transform.position = _segments[_segments.Count - 1].transform.position;
    segment.Type = _segments[_segments.Count - 1].Type;

    _segments.Add(segment);
}
```

and finally you only need to check and set the orientation once, namely where you move the head => You only ever need to set the type for the very first segment - No need to check position of the segments around it, all you need is the previous and current direction of the head and apply it to the very first segment after updating all others.

So something like e.g.

```
// again assuming that is what you re using
[SerializeField] private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    // Update all segments except first (after head)
    for (int i = _segments.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        _segments[i].position = _segments[i - 1].position;
        _segments[i].Type = _segments[i - 1].Type;
    }

    // also update position of first segment (after head)
    // the type is more complex see below
    _segments[0].position = transform.position;

    // Update head position
    transform.position = new Vector3(
        Mathf.Round(transform.position.x + _direction.x),
        Mathf.Round(transform.position.y + _direction.y)
    );

    // Update head orientation
    // here someone might come up with a more beautiful solution ^^
    var previousSprite = spriteRenderer.sprite;
    var newSprite = previousSprite;
    if(_direction.x < 0) newSprite = SnakeHeadLeft;
    else if(_direction.x > 0) newSprite = SnakeHeadRight;
    else if(_direction.y < 0) newSprite = SnakeHeadDown;
    else if(_direction.y > 0) newSprite = SnakeHeadUp;
    else Debug.LogError("Snake isn't moving?!", this);
    
    // finally update first segment (after head) orientation
    if(previousSprite == newSprite)
    {
        // snake is moving straight => no corner
        _segments[0].Type = newSprite == SnakeHeadLeft || newSprite == SnakeHeadRight
                                ? SegmentType.horizontal : SementType.vertical;
    }
    // Otherwise there now can be 8 changes in direction resulting in 4 corners
    else if(previousSprite == SnakeHeadUp && newSprite == SnakeHeadLeft
            || previousSprite == SnakeHeadRight && newSprite == SnakeHeadDown)
    {
        _segments[0].Type = CornerLeftDown;
    }
    else if(previousSprite == SnakeHeadUp && newSprite == SnakeHeadRight
            || previousSprite == SnakeHeadLeft && newSprite == SnakeHeadDown)
    {
        _segments[0].Type = CornerRightDown;
    }
    else if(previousSprite == SnakeHeadDown && newSprite == SnakeHeadLeft
            || previousSprite == SnakeHeadRight && newSprite == SnakeHeadUp)
    {
        _segments[0].Type = CornerLeftUp;
    }
    else if(previousSprite == SnakeHeadDown && newSprite == SnakeHeadRight
            || previousSprite == SnakeHeadLeft && newSprite == SnakeHeadUp)
    {
        _segments[0].Type = CornerRightUp;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("An impossible direction change has occurred! From {previousSprite} to {newSprite}", this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! This is such a thorough and amazing answer!

I wish I could upvote twice, but yes, this completely sort my issue out entirely! Incredible.

Thank you for this answer. : )

Answer (score 1):

If the `SnakeBody` game object is a child of the `SnakeHead` game object, then you should just be able to use `transform.parent.GetComponent<Snake>();` in the `SnakeBodySprites` script. However, you have `GetComponentInParent()` commented out, which makes me suspect that you tried this but `SnakeBody` was not actually a child of `SnakeHead` but a separate, independent game object.

If you look in the object list in the editor you should see the `SnakeBody` object nested under the `SnakeHead` object to verify that it is indeed a child of `SnakeHead`. Alternatively, if you forgot to specify the type for `GetComponentInParent()`, you can try `GetComponentInParent<Snake>();`.